# Different view appearances in iOS7/iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

In my app I need to support iOS 7 and iOS 8. I use Xcode 6. When I build app for iPhone 5s (iOS 8.0) it looks like this:

[image: Correct Layout]

and it's right. But when I build app for iPhone 5s (iOS 7.1) it looks like this:

[image: Incorrect layout]

so button Done is missed and some black lines appeared. It looks like Xcode built app for iPhone 4. Maybe I forgot to set some properties and I can't understand what exactly properties I forgot. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added the launchscreen.xib to the project

Comment: why do you build it twice?

Comment: do you have a launch IMAGE .. ios7 and below need images

Comment: @RameshMuthe, Daij-Djan I added launchscreen.xib but didn't add images in it. Will test it with images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the appropriate Launch images.

Edit: Just tested a new project and black bars disappeared just by clicking "Use Asset catalog" even if you don't actually set images.

[image]

Comment: how would that help with ios7?

Comment: Actually this issue is faced when xcode does not pick up the launch images according to their asset name....